# Converting numeric date value to a date with month in first three letters - Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have wrote a code in SF as below

```
 select to_date(date_part(day,current_date)||'-'||monthname(current_date)||'-'||right(date_part(year,current_date),2),'DD-MON-YY')
```

the output need to be 16-Feb-22. when i run this one, it gives you 16-02-2022. How to convert this to 16-Feb-22? But this need to be in date format. Not the string format

I was doin this as an exception of TO_DATE(current_date,'DD-MON-RR')

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

```
alter session set DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YY';
select current_date();
alter session unset DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT;
```

Comment: Thank you @reacbgk . what if twe have a custom date. I have used current date for this. What if i have a table and a date column in it? how to add a column for this?

Comment: @SnyderFox You can replace current_date() with the column name from the table. As long as you have set the DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT for the session, any query you run in that session will return dates in that format



`alter session set DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YY';
select date_column_name from table_name;
alter session unset DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TO_VARCHAR function with a date format:

```
select to_varchar(current_date, 'DD-MON-YY');
```

If you convert it back to a date, it will display using the default for the session, so you'll need to convert it this way or alter the session default for display.